# Need help finding average and printing out errors

Tags: java, exception

I need help solving this school problem. Here's a link if you're interested: http://go.code-check.org/codecheck/files/14121519036ltx4u6e3i9mtrqynsyhgihr7

When I tried to solve the problem, I print out the right messages, but there's a problem. I'm suspecting that in the Driver of the Codecheck is something like System.out.println("Average = " + message);, or something like that. So, I would end up with a result that gave

Average = squeeze.txt does not have numeric data

which is not what I want. How should I solve this if the Driver is giving me this issue? Here's what I have currently:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Average {

    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner in;
    String myName;
    public Average(String name){
        myName = name;
        try{
            in = new Scanner(new File(name));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + myName + " (The system cannot find the file specified)");
        }
    }

    public String scanDataAndCalculateAverage(){
        try{
            if (!in.hasNext())
                throw new Exception(myName + " is empty");
            else 
                while (in.hasNextLong()){
                    total += in.nextLong();
                    count++;
                }
            if (in.hasNext()){
                throw new Exception(myName + " does not have numerical data");
            }
            else return "" + (total / count);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: My new constructor:

public Average(String name)throws Exception{

```
    myName = name;
    try{
        in = new Scanner(new File(name));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw new Exception("Error: " + myName + " (No such file or directory)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you are throwing an Exception, which is getting printed by some error handling code in the driver.  Because you have that exact text in your exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is this part:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    return e.getMessage();
}
```

You're catching any Exception and returning the message as a String. Therefore, the call of the method `scanDataAndCalculateAverage` finishes "normally" and the "code checker" writes `Average =` in front of the returned String, since it believes that your program returned a valid value.

You need to propagate the Exception to the calling method so it knows that something gone wrong.

Since it seems to be an assignment, *you* should try to fix that. If you have a question about that, then leave a comment.

Btw, please change the following Exception messages:

1. `"Error: " + myName + " (The system cannot find the file specified)"` should be `"Error: " + myName + " (No such file or directory)"`
2. `myName + " does not have numerical data"` should be `myName + "does not have numeric data"`

The check won't pass if you use your messages. Strange, that the first one was mentioned by the assignment, but it uses a different one to do the checking.

This is the expected output of the whole check:

```
Average = 49.91791791791792
squeeze.txt does not have numeric data
empty.txt is empty
Error: notThere.txt (No such file or directory)
Average = 0.0
```

Comment: Hi. I propagated my scanDataAndCalculateAverage() method and solved that issue, but I now have an issue with the constructor. Whenever the program tries to run with a file that does not exist or is not at the location, I would get this error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown + avg4.scanDataAndCalculateAverage());. Got an idea how I should solve this, since propagating it didn't work (or maybe I did that part wrong?)?

Comment: Since you're using a [`checked Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) you have to handle them. Either by adding a `throws` clause to the method head or with a `try/catch` block. The first one won't work, because the "checker" doesn't expect that :P. And the second possibility won't help us here either. So you need to use `unchecked Exceptions` instead. For example `throw new RuntimeException("...")`. If this is something new, then you might need to find another way.

Comment: I'm still having the issue. I might be not understanding something here, as I do not understand the terms well. I'll edit the post to show you my new constructor.

Comment: @Yazeth Why have you changed your constructor? Your problem is in the `scanDataAndCalculateAverage` method and not in the constructor. You don't have to change "him".

Comment: Oh, I just suspected that since it fails whenever it tries to use a nonexisting file, I just guessed that the constructor had an issue.

Comment: @Yazeth Use your normal constructor and check that code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the input file contains something that is not a valid long. See that you have these lines:

```
while (in.hasNextLong()){
    total += in.nextLong(); 
    count++;
}
if (in.hasNext()){
    throw new Exception(myName + " does not have numerical data");
}
```

So if your file has something different from a `long` you will exit the loop, and then the `if` will send you the message you posted.

To find the exact thing that is causing the problem change this line:

```
throw new Exception(myName + " does not have numerical data");
```

to this:

```
throw new Exception(myName + " does not have numerical data: (" + in.next() + ")");
```